# I'm on '4.3.0-kali1-amd-64' but cannot install linux-headers?

Tags: kali-linux

I have typed

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

And I am trying to install linux-headers on Kali-Linux 2016.1

> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 394 not upgraded

So I typed

```
uname -r
```

And got this as a response

> 4.3.0-kali1-amd64

Then I type

```
apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

then get this error

> E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd-64
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64'

Can anyone please help me, I have tried a lot of things and none of them work?

Answer (score 1):

4.3 is outdated, you need to upgrade your Kali Linux distribution to the latest (4.4) and install headers:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

Then you'll be able to get the headers:

```
apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

---

Alternatively you can try getting the header files from another repository. Add the following repo to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```